# Do I need to create class implement MKAnnotation protocol for different type to annotation?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have 2 annotation types say A and B every time I pin a new A annotation I want to delete previous A-pin, but not B-pin this situation is the same with B-pin. Both pins contain just a location and title. Question is can I use MKPointAnnotation and add some kind of tag to separate these two kind of pins for easily unpin or I need to implement two classes for each pin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create two classes or create one class and add a "annotationType" property.

The MKPointAnnotation class doesn't have a tag property.